# Variable storage update across react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js, use-state

This is a next/react project.
folder structure:

```
components > Navbar.js

pages > index.js (/ route)(includes Navbar)
      > submitCollection.js (/submitCollection)(includes Navbar)
```

I am trying to have the user submit a specific string as an input and i store it inside the account variable.
Navbar.js

```
const Navbar = ({}) => {
    
    const [account,setAccount] = useState()
    
    const handleClick = () => {
        setAccount(randomNumberThatIHaveGenerated)
    }
    ...
    return (
        <Link href="/">home</Link>
        <Link href="/submitCollection">submit collection</Link>
        ...
        <button onClick={handleClick} >press to set account</button>
        ...
        {account?(<p>{account}</p>):(<p>u need to set an accout</p>)}
    )
}
```

when i visit home using the navbar link, the account is again set to undefineed and i need to press the button again in order to set it. How can i make the string remain set. like persist on the navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem using `localstorage` and `useEffect`

Adding this piece of code to your work will do the trick

```
const [account,setAccount] = useState(localStorage.getItem('account') ?localStorage.getItem('account') : null)


useEffect(()=>{
localstorage.setItem(account)
},[account])
```

For example

```
const [account,setAccount] = useState(localStorage.getItem('account') ?localStorage.getItem('account') : null)
    useEffect(()=>{
localStorage.setItem('account',account)
},[account])
    const handleClick = () => {
        setAccount(randomNumberThatIHaveGenerated)
    }
```

Hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

`useState` is not persistent, it is bound to its component, in order to make it persist, you have to use `localStorage`

```
const [account,_setAccount] = useState();
const setAccount = (val) => {
  _setAccount(val);
  localStorage.setItem('account', val);
}

useEffect(() => {
  const storedAccount = localStorage.getItem('account');
  if (storedAccount) _setAccount(storedAccount);
}, [])
    
const handleClick = () => {
  setAccount(randomNumberThatIHaveGenerated)
}
```

`useEffect` is called when the component renders, check for stored account and displays it.

And notice how we reimplement `setAccount`, so that everytime it is called, we update the localStorage.

You can also create a custom hook with this logic, so the component would look cleaner. Or even better, use something like [use-state-persist](https://github.com/leoafarias/use-state-persist)